# How to retrieve GPO Settings

Tags: java, ldap, gpo

I am struggling with the following issue while trying to retrieve all GPO of a domain with Java. I was able to create a connection to Active Directory and get the policy objects, however I am not able to retrieve their settings in which I am interested in.

I was only able to retrieve the following properties:
CanonicalName
CN
Created
createTimeStamp
Deleted
Description
DisplayName
DistinguishedName
dSCorePropagationData
flags
gPCFileSysPath
gPCFunctionalityVersion
gPCMachineExtensionNames
gPCUserExtensionNames
instanceType
isCriticalSystemObject
isDeleted
LastKnownParent
Modified
modifyTimeStamp
Name
nTSecurityDescriptor
ObjectCategory
ObjectClass
ObjectGUID
ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion
sDRightsEffective
showInAdvancedViewOnly
systemFlags
uSNChanged
uSNCreated
versionNumber
whenChanged
whenCreated

Do you know how should I face this issue? Is there any extended property from which I can retrieve the settings of each GPO?

I do not know if the code would be useful as it is just a connection and a ldap query:

```
colAttributes = {"*"};
strSearchRoot = "DC=xx,DC=xx";
this.getActiveDirectoryConnection().setRequestControl(null, Control.NONCRITICAL);
colSearchResult = this.getActiveDirectoryConnection().getQuery(colAttributes, "(ObjectClass=groupPolicyContainer)", strSearchRoot);
    while (colSearchResult.hasMoreElements())
    {
        objSearchResult = (SearchResult) colSearchResult.nextElement();
        objAttributes = objSearchResult.getAttributes();
    }

private void getActiveDirectoryConnection()
{
    return new ActiveDirectory(strDomain, strUsername, strPassword);
}
```

An example of I am trying to get is the Default Domain Policy, not only this but all policies. And settings goes through Password Settings such as maxPwdAge, lockoutThreshold, etc Screen and Power Settings, between others

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.Control;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.PagedResultsControl;
import javax.naming.ldap.PagedResultsResponseControl;
public class ActiveDirectory
{
    private LdapContext objLDAPContext;
    public ActiveDirectory(String strURL, String strUserName, String strPassword) throws NamingException
    {
        Hashtable<String, Object> objEnvironment;
        objEnvironment = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
        objEnvironment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        objEnvironment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  strURL);
        objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, strUserName);
        objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, strPassword);
        objEnvironment.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectGUID");
        try
        {
            this.objLDAPContext = new InitialLdapContext(objEnvironment, null);
        }
        catch (NamingException objException)
        {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "certificates".concat(File.separator).concat("cacerts"));
            objEnvironment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, strURL.replace("LDAP:", "LDAPS:").replace(":389", ":636"));
        }
        this.objLDAPContext = new InitialLdapContext(objEnvironment, null);
    }
    private LdapContext getContext()
    {
        return this.objLDAPContext;
    }
    public NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> getQuery(String[] colAttributes, String strLDAPFilter, String strSearchRoot) throws NamingException
    {
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> objAnswer;
        SearchControls objSearchControls = new SearchControls();
        objSearchControls.setReturningAttributes(colAttributes);
        objSearchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        objAnswer = this.getContext().search(strSearchRoot, strLDAPFilter, objSearchControls);
        return objAnswer;
    }
    public void close() throws NamingException
    {
        this.getContext().close();
    }
    public void setRequestControl(byte[] objCookie, boolean bolControl)
    {
        int intPageSize;
        intPageSize = 1000;
        try
        {
            this.getContext().setRequestControls(new Control[]
            {
                new PagedResultsControl(intPageSize, objCookie, bolControl)
            });
        }
        catch(NamingException | IOException objException)
        {
            //No more pages could be recovered
        }
    }
    public byte[] getCookie()
    {
        byte[] objCookie;
        objCookie = null;
        try
        {
            Control[] objControl = this.getContext().getResponseControls();
            if (objControl != null)
            {
                for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < objControl.length; intCounter++)
                {
                    if (objControl[intCounter] instanceof PagedResultsResponseControl)
                    {
                        PagedResultsResponseControl objPagedControl = (PagedResultsResponseControl) objControl[intCounter];
                        objCookie = objPagedControl.getCookie();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(NamingException objException)
        {
            //Skip errors null cookie will be handled
        }
        return objCookie;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 show your code. 2 Name at least a few of the policy objects you wanted.  3 Have they been set? Does the object have a value if it has not been set?

Comment: OK, what does "this.getActiveDirectoryConnection()" do?

Comment: It just create a LDAPContext. that you can use for make queries to Active Directory. In this case the context is already created and I make a LDAP Query that retrieves all the attributes of (ObjectClass=groupPolicyContainer). Query is working properly, I just can not get the attribute that I need

Comment: I am trying to  dupiclate your code so I can test it.  It woudl be better if I used the same code to access the Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get gpo settings through LDAP, because gpo templates has been stored in sysvol folder in domain controller.It is a shared folder across the domain. We can get the path of GPO templates by GPO container attribute gPLink. If you access the file you can get all applied gpo settings